# Insert elements in numpy array given X and Y index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.full([20, 20], 0)

x = [3, 6, 3, 6]
y = [18, 18, 19, 19]

print(b)
for _x, _y in zip(y, x):
    b[_x][_y] = 1
    pass

print('\n')

print(b)
```

However, I don't understand some of the things in there, such as the x and y coordinates. Why are they flipped?
Is there any cleaner way to implement this using a built-in numpy function?

Comment: How about `b[y,x] = 1`? Well with `b(x,y)`, `x` would be the first axis, i.e. Y-axis on cartesian coords and `y` would be `X-axis` on cartesian being the second axis of an array.

Comment: It doesn't populate the array, though

Comment: You populate with `b = np.full([20, 20], 0)` and then do that.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that it doesn't insert the ones at those coordinates

Comment: Flip those x,y : `b[x,y] = 1`?

Comment: Doesn't numpy follow the x and y plane we see in math?

Comment: NumPy doesn't have the concept of `x,y`, but has axis. If you are strictly working with 2D data, maybe its worth looking into NumPy matrix class.

Answer (score 0):

```
for _x, _y in zip(y, x):
```

is borked, zip 'em in the order you intend to use them

```
for _x, _y in zip(x,y):
```

then

```
print(*b, sep='\n')
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  1.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
```

Comment: Interesting. What's the purpose of the star?

Comment: unpacks the array one level

Answer (score 0):

Create a smaller array (easier to display), and a pair of indices (forget the x,y labels):

```
In [270]: arr = np.zeros((10,10), int)
In [271]: I = [3,6,3,6]
In [272]: J = [4,4,5,5]
In [273]: for i,j in zip(I,J):
     ...:     arr[i,j] = i+j     # note the [i,j] indexing
In [274]: arr
Out[274]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],  # row 3
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0],  # row 6
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
#                      col 4 5
```

We could have set the values directly with the `I,J` lists; or we can retrieve the values:

```
In [275]: arr[I,J]
Out[275]: array([ 7, 10,  8, 11])
```

The convention with `numpy` 2d arrays, the first index is displayed as rows, the 2nd as columns.

`np.meshgrid` has an indexing parameter that accomodates different labeling:

```
In [279]: np.meshgrid([3,6],[4,5],indexing='xy')
Out[279]: 
[array([[3, 6],
        [3, 6]]), 
 array([[4, 4],
        [5, 5]])]
In [280]: np.meshgrid([3,6],[4,5],indexing='ij')
Out[280]: 
[array([[3, 3],
        [6, 6]]), 
 array([[4, 5],
        [4, 5]])]
```

Displaying the array is one thing, plotting it as a scatter plot or image is another.

The default `imshow` parameters display the array the same orientation, with origin in the upper left.

```
plt.imshow(arr,origin='upper')
```

I really should have given the array different dimensions, e.g.

```
In [289]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [290]: arr
Out[290]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The `(3,4)` shape is displayed as 3 rows, 4 columns.  This is a wide spread practice when talking about arrays and/or matrices.